# JS and ExpressionEngine - Remove KV pairs by duplicate values only?

Tags: javascript, arrays, expressionengine, key-value

We're building a site with ExpressionEngine. We are running a SQL query to gather up all member IDs for a specific member group. After that, we are using EE tags to get data from a custom member field for each member ID.

The ID and field data need to stay paired, as we will be populating a drop-down so that the ID is the value and the field data is the text, so we are currently putting them into a JS array as key/value pairs. The call is as follows:

```
var array= [
{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_members WHERE group_id = 5"}
    {exp:member:custom_profile_data
        member_id="{member_id}"}
        {if company != ''}
            {{member_id}:"{company}"}, 
        {/if}
    {/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
{/exp:query}
};
```

This gives us the output:

```
var array = [
    {1:"name01"},
    {2:"name02"},
    {3:"name01"},
    {4:"name03"}
];
```

Now, our problem. We need to remove objects based on duplicate field data (values) only, so the above array would look like this:

```
var array = [
    {1:"name01"},
    {2:"name02"},
    {4:"name03"}
];
```

None of these IDs (keys) will ever be the same, but the field data (values) can be. So we want to keep the first KV pair that comes through with a unique value, but remove any subsequent dupes of that value - despite the fact that they will not be true "duplicate values" due to a different ID (key).

Keeping in mind that the KV pairs are all dynamic, is there any possible way to do this via JS so we can create a new array for the cleaned data to pass to the drop-down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the duplications by modifying your MySQL query. (In my example, my custom field ID was 1.)

```
var myArray = [];
{exp:query sql="SELECT MIN(m.member_id) AS co_member_id, d.m_field_id_1 AS company FROM exp_members m INNER JOIN exp_member_data d ON m.member_id = d.member_id WHERE d.m_field_id_1 != '' AND m.group_id > 0 GROUP BY d.m_field_id_1;"}
    myArray.push({{co_member_id}: "{company}"});
{/exp:query}
```

This query would use the first (in the ordinal sense) member_id found; you could also change the MIN to MAX and get the last.

This will give you a clean output in your source, without the need for any additional JS processing. I'd also recommend changing the names of the variables you're outputting as to not conflict in EE's parsing.

Comment: Very elegant. I like keeping as much of this in the query as possible. Killer work. mido22's  answer is perfect for JS implementation, but this solution is definitely preferred for use within the confines of EE. Many thanks. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like...

```
function removeDups(arry){
    var tmp = {}, retainIdx=[], newArry=[];
    arry.forEach(function(obj, idx){
        var val = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
        if(val && !tmp[val]){
            retainIdx.push(idx);
            tmp[val] = true;
        }
    });
    retainIdx.forEach(function(i){
        newArry.push(arry[i]);
    });

    return newArry;
};
```